# DWT layout folders are throwing error after Web 8.5 Upgrade

Tags: web8.5, upgrade

After upgrading Tridion 2013 SP1 to Web 8.5 we are not able to open the folder which holds DWT layouts. The error is

```
Unable to get template type with ID 8 for item tcm:xx-xxxxxx-2048
```

looks like the specified layout with this tcm ID is creating some problem and due to this the folder is not rendering any items.
Any ideas?
The issue is also unique in its way because we have two CME servers which shares same database. Its working fine for one server but not the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Razor seems to be registered with different id or its not installed at your CMS server, but template expecting it with Id:8

Check your Tridion.ContentManager.config, it should be like below:

> ```
>  <add id="8" name="RazorTemplate" mimeType="text/x-tcm-cshtml"
> hasBinaryContent="false"
>  contentHandler="Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.RazorContentHandler,
>  Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor, Version=1.3.3.1, Culture=neutral,
>  PublicKeyToken=5eeceedb34d9dfd7">
>     <webDavFileExtensions>
>      <add itemType="TemplateBuildingBlock" fileExtension="cshtml" />
>     </webDavFileExtensions>   </add>
> ```

If your Publisher is out-scaled to another server (separate to your Content Manager server), then you will also need to install, and configure, the Razor Mediator on that server too.

It is also worth noting that you have to restart the Tridion Publisher Windows Service after installing (or making any configuration changes to) the Razor Mediator.

Comment: Thanks Sudhakar. Yes we are yet to install the Razor mediator in our environments. The only thing bothering me is why is it working on on CME and not on other? I will let you know if it gets fixed by Razor. I will check the id in config as well.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may be missing the Tridion Razor Mediator or another custom mediator (or it's not configured correctly).

https://github.com/alex-klock/razor-mediator-4-tridion

Comment: Yes we are yet to install the Razor mediator in our environments. The only thing bothering me is why is it working on on CME and not on other? I will let you know if it gets fixed by Razor.

Answer (score 1):

You mention:

> we are not able to open the folder which holds DWT layouts

But looking at the error, I think that statement isn't entirely true, since the Folder you are unable to open does not only contain DWT layouts, but seems to contain an undefined Template Type.

When you upgrade your system you need to make sure you complete the entire upgrade, which means you also need to install/enable all customizations which you had on the other system, and you need to make sure the configurations are identical on all of your out-scaled environments.

In the comments on the other answers you mention you didn't install the Razor mediator yet, but the templates can be opened on one of your CME server and not on another. This seems to indicate that the Razor mediator (or at least an additional Template Type with the ID 8) is configured on the CME server that is working, and not on the other where you are getting the error.

Your question does not contain enough information to fully answer your question, but I think with the information given in mine and the other answers, you should have enough pointers to solve your problem.